# Too many open files @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am raising this problem again and again on my live server. Please help me out with the problem. My project is on windows so how I can increase the limit on windows.

I have seen the solution but this is given for Ubuntu. How I can do the same on windows?

```
EMFILE is too many files opened in your process.
ENFILE is too many files opened in the entire system.
```

So Errno::EMFILE is due to the ruby process opening too many files. This limit is probably set to the default 1024 can be seen with:

$ulimit -n
1024

Instead of:

$ulimit
unlimited

Comment: Possible fix [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/File-descriptor-limit-on-Windows-is-causing-Too-Many-Open-Files-error-in-Maya.html), but a better question is: Why are you opening so many files??!! Sounds like a bug in the code to me... Can you try to trace what's causing it and show the code?

Comment: @TomLord there is something wrong with the server.

Comment: It is not normal for a rails application to simultaneously open more than 1024 files...

Comment: @TomLord my project is live and around 5000 users are using the application may be because of that server is crashing rapidly . so, is there any way to fix this .

Comment: *"is there any way to fix this"* -- Step one is to diagnose the cause of the problem. I'd start by doing that. Do you have something that writes lots of temporary files, e.g. for reporting or uploads? Do you have lots of log files being created, or stale cache files, etc? Find out *what's going wrong* before trying to fix it.